# Pure Functional Programming with Path Dependent Types (Parsers) in Scala?

Tags: scala, parsing, path-dependent-type, parboiled2

So when using Scala Parsers one may have:

```
case class MyParser(foos: List[String]) extends Parsers {
  val bars: List[Parser[String]] = foos.map(parserFromString)

  // Expensive function
  def parserFromString(s: String): Parser[String] = ???
}
```

`Parser` is a path-dependent type, so this code cannot be refactored so that `bars` can be passed in from the constructor.  Note that `parserFromString` in my use case actually creates a `MyParser` in such a way that `MyParser` construction becomes O(N!) where `N = foos.size`.

So suppose now I wish to add to `bars` via another `foo`. The FP way would be to refactor to include `bars` in the constructor, then define something like `def +(foo: String): MyParser = copy(bars = bars :+ parserFromString(foo)`, but as mentioned I can't I have to recreate from scratch.

My solution is just make `bars` a `private var` and mutate it with a `Unit` method `update`, i.e. `def update(foo: String): Unit = bars +:= parserFromString(foo)`

My first question is quite simple: am I stuck? Do I have to use mutation?

Second question: does Parboiled2 suffer from this? Do they use path-dependent types (at a glance it doesn't look like it), and if so why do Scala parsers use path-dependent types?

If parboiled2 does not suffer from path-dependent types this alone can be a reason to use it!

*If anyone is wondering why I need to create `Parser`s from parameters it's because I'm implementing a language where users can define macros and use those macros in defining other macros. So no, before anyone tries telling me to change the design, I can't. I also really don't want mutability since I'm going to be needing multi-threading later.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Parser` is a path-dependent type, so this code cannot be refactored so that bars can be passed in from the constructor.

Yes, it can:

```
// could also be trait and mixed in where you need it
object MyParsers extends Parsers {
  case class MyParser(bars: List[Parser[String]]) {
    def +(foo: String): MyParser = copy(bars = bars :+ parserFromString(foo))
    ...
  }
}
```

> does Parboiled2 suffer from this? Do they use path-dependent types (at a glance it doesn't look like it)

No, as you can see from the [examples](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/examples).

> and if so why do Scala parsers use path-dependent types

As shown above, this shouldn't be a problem. I *have* run into trouble with path-dependent types in some circumstances, but not in use of parsers.

For choice between Scala-parsers and parboiled, I'd personally think more about performance, which DSL you prefer, etc. Last time I've looked at parboiled, it had no real way to affect error reporting, but this [is fixed now](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/#error-reporting).

Comment: Hmm, thanks, good point.  Could you answer the second part of my question?

Comment: Thanks again for this, we recently put the effort in and refactored quite a lot of code to use this pattern and it now the code is very nice. Don't understand why I didn't see this when I initially wrote the code - guess this was the first time I've seen path-dependent types.